# Getting Name Value JSON in PIG

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

Hi guys i just started doing pig, I was wondering if JsonLoader is capable of parsing all value inside json.

for example:

```
{"food":"Tacos", "person":"Alice", "amount":3}
```

and i need to get "food" stored as a relation in chararray and "Tacos" which is the value of "food" to another relation.

after reading many tutorial and documentation, i havent found a built in method to do so.

does it mean that the only solution to this is through UDF?

thanks a lot!

Comment: @Zelldon UDF = User Defined Function. If you don't know about Apache Pig, please don't post rude comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer that is to use external jar from twitter.

```
register 'hdfs:/udf/elephant-bird-pig-4.10.jar';
register 'hdfs:/udf/elephant-bird-core-4.10.jar';
register 'hdfs:/udf/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.10.jar';
register 'hdfs:/udf/json-simple-1.1.1.jar';
```

test.json

```
{"food":"Tacos", "person":"Alice", "amount":3}
```

script:

```
A = LOAD 'hdfs:/test.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS (json:map[]); 
DUMP A;
```

and the output that i wanted is:

```
([amount#3,food#Tacos,person#Alice])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

input- pig.json

```
{"food":"Tacos", "person":"Alice", "amount":3}
```

script

```
A = LOAD '/home/kishore/Data/Pig/pig.json' USING JsonLoader('food:chararray,person:chararray,amount:int');
B = foreach A generate food,person,amount;
Dump B;
```

output

```
(Tacos,Alice,3)
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but how do you get the 'name field' which is "food" to a relation? because there are scenarios in field name may change so i need to get both name & value field to pair them with map.